# App runs on emulator but not on device

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a simple app that runs on the emulator, but now that i am trying to run it on a DroidX device it get Forced Closed messages immediately. The debugger logcat says it is "caused by: java.lang.ClassNOtFoundException: com.beam.Beam in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader{/data/app/com.beam..."

I have targeted SDKI7, with Min SDK version 7.

Im guessing that the app is either not loading into the device memory or eclipse can't find it in the device to run it.

Here's my Logcat message:

```
02-28 17:23:57.911: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(15353): Shutting down VM
02-28 17:23:57.911: WARN/dalvikvm(15353): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400208b0)
02-28 17:23:57.969: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15353): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 17:23:57.969: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15353): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.concbeam3.ConcBeam3: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.concbeam3.ConcBeam3 in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.concbeam3-2.apk]
02-28 17:23:57.969: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15353):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.makeApplication(ActivityThread.java:661)
02-28 17:23:57.969: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15353):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4306)
02-28 17:23:57.969: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15353):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:129)
02-28 17:23:57.969: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15353):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2145)
02-28 17:23:57.969: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15353):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-28 17:23:57.969: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15353):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
02-28 17:23:57.969: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15353):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4701)
02-28 17:23:57.969: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15353):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 17:23:57.969: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15353):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-28 17:23:57.969: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15353):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-28 17:23:57.969: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15353):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-28 17:23:57.969: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15353):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-28 17:23:57.969: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15353): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.concbeam3.ConcBeam3 in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.concbeam3-2.apk]
02-28 17:23:57.969: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15353):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
02-28 17:23:57.969: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15353):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
02-28 17:23:57.969: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15353):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
02-28 17:23:57.969: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15353):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:942)
02-28 17:23:57.969: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15353):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.makeApplication(ActivityThread.java:656)
02-28 17:23:57.969: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15353):     ... 11 more
02-28 17:23:57.992: WARN/ActivityManager(17919):   Force finishing activity com.concbeam3/.Main
```

Comment: Have you tried checking your LogCat output?

Comment: yes..that's how I know I have the ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: Does it show up in your app drawer? If it does its installed. Try clicking it. If nothing happens or you get a FC then its a problem with the code.

Comment: It can happen if you are using a specific library which is not available on the device but is on the phone. One common example is google maps. Please verify

Comment: Eclipse does load it into the apps menu on the device. If I click the icon I get the FC. If it's in my code, why does the emulator work so well. Are the emulators that bad at emulating?

Comment: The only libraries I import are for the java and android methods.

Answer (score 1):

This is one step you can take - if you are using eclipse right click on your project and go to Android. Check the build target or change it to your Phones Platform. Also make sure that Debugging mode is ON on your phone. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

i noticed the uppercase B on /data/app/com.**Beam** is it a mistype or did you copy paste it. Maybe its a casesensitive/windows/linux type of issue.

You could check if you spelled it somewhere with an uppercase B.